# Html input field value attribute is different from display value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, struts, struts-tags

I have a simple JSP form (uses struts tags) that get populated by a struts value object.
One of the HTML input field has its value attribute different from what is displayed.
But if form is submitted it submits the correct value(value attribute)

Does anybody know why displayed value is different from the actual value (attribute value)?

Thanks,
Tan.

Comment: you mean the placeholder value?

Comment: Can you see in the html (view source or Firebug inspect element) what html code is generated.

Comment: Yes, placeholder value is different from actual value.

Comment: HTML code is correct with the correct value attribute. But displayed value is not the attribute value.

Comment: Opened in firebug and tried to edit the HTML code. Then it displayed the correct value. Nothing has been changed but just added a space and removed it. Suddenly correct value appeared in the field.

Comment: Finally resolved the issue myself. Had to set the value in the text box using java-script. Still not sure what cause the attribute value different from displayed value.